# Fix some scratches on my Macbook pro

Tags: unibody, scratches

please how can I repair these scratches on my Macbook pro they made me so sad.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The blemishes I see in your pictures are not what I'd call scratches, they're dents!

Comment: You could colorware it then the scratches/dents wouldn't be noticeable lol.

Answer (score 1):

Apple will put a new case around your existing working components for a flat rate repair - probably $350 these days, but I haven't checked.

You would want to [file down the aluminum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000NPUKYS) if it protrudes, but that won't look much better than the ragged dings you have shown. Unlike steel, aluminum doesn't repair well and the anodized coating that Apple performs to make the pebbled surface isn't something you can DIY replicate.

If you're just concerned with color, you might be able to get some modeling paint to make it a bit closer to the shade, but on close inspection it won't fool anyone. If that goes badly, you can still file off the paint and use sandpaper which is the last thing I would mention - that really looks bad in my opinion, so I would avoid that unless you are ready to pay for an Apple repair if you don't like what the grit of the sandpaper does to the finish.

Small metal files are much easier to control and limit the area of "rework" so unless you have sharp edges, I would leave it alone if you want to keep the area looking new as opposed to feeling smooth.

Comment: Files will really mess up the finish. And Apple spent a **lot** of money getting the finish *just so.* BMIKE is correct that the only real way to fix it is a new case. But if you want to go the "clean up the edges" routine I would find some **very** fine abrasive paper (sandpaper...) on the order of 800 to 1000 grit. Try a store that sells auto painting supplies as that grit of abrasive is commonly used for wet sanding automotive finishes.

Comment: SteveChambers, IMO the images are of poor quality and I would not rule out the proper use of Cut 6 Extra Fine Escapement File to knock down the high spots, tape off to prevent sounding areas from being damaged.  Then finish with [ISO/FEPA (P-scale) Super Fine and Ultra Fine Sandpaper](http://www.seabean.com/polish/GritScales.pdf) that I would cut and adhere to e.g. flattened popsicle stick with ultra thin double sided tape or fine spray adhesive. Again keeping the sounding areas taped to protect. Then finish off with the higher grit wrapped to a curved radius object to lightly touch as needed.

Comment: I would encourage @user3439894 to edit the recommendations into my answer or make a "good sandpaper" techniques and supplies answer. your knowledge is too good to be buried in a comment IMO :-)

Comment: @SteveChambers please consider yourself also asked to edit my post or answer for points :-) Thanks - I've not found a grit that doesn't make things too "shiny" but I have some mangled cases to test on next week.

Comment: Thanks guys, could someone please provide me a video or some tutorial for how to use sandpaper with macbook or any device?